# Dashboard for SharePoint server health

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, .net, health-analyzer, dashboard

I want to create a dashboard to show the health of SharePoint servers using .NET code (C#). Anyone suggest me some ideas???

Comment: This question I broad enough to be out of scope for this community. Do you think you can narrow it down by adding more details and an expected outcome?